# Print image in Printer Thermal - A920 Pro - Delphi 10.2 firemonkey

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, thermal-printer

I'm trying to print qr code, on a thermal pos bluetooth printer in delphi, android platform (firemonkey). the printer is connected, I can print the text, but I can't I can't print the qr code,
I would be grateful if someone can help.

i want to send qr code as image to printer

URL := 'http://www.exampes.com/176216271352002021.png';

[image]

this is the code i use in delphi-android 10.2.

```
URL := 'http://www.examles.com/176216271352002021.png';
Podaci.NetHTTPClient1.Get(URL);
```

---

```
procedure TPodaci.NetHTTPClient1RequestCompleted(const Sender: TObject;
  const AResponse: IHTTPResponse);
   var
  strm   : TStream;
  pngImg : TBitmap;
begin {0}
  strm   := TStream.Create;
  pngImg := TBitmap.Create;

  strm   := AResponse.ContentStream;
  pngImg.LoadFromStream(strm);
  ImageGl :=pngImg;
 // imgPict.Picture.Graphic := pngImg;

  FreeAndNil(pngImg);   // OK always
  FreeAndNil(strm);     // Here is something strange.

end;


          // Reset Printer
         ostream.write(StringToJA(chr(27) + chr(64),'iso8859-2') ) ;
        //podaci o firmi
         ostream.write(StringToJA(escBoldOn,'iso8859-2') ) ;
         ostream.write(StringToJA('TEST' +escNewLine    , 'iso8859-2'));
         ostream.write(StringToJA(escNewLine    , 'iso8859-2'));
         ostream.write(StringToJA('================================' +escNewLine , 'iso8859-2'));
         ostream.write(StringToJA( BitmapToStr(ImageGl,'','')));  // print images 
         ostream.write(StringToJA(chr(27) + chr(64),'iso8859-2') );
         Sleep(250);
         ostream.flush();
         ostream.close;
```

the image conversion function I use now, but I don't even know if it's good .

```
    function TPodaci.BitmapToStr(BMP: TBitmap; EscapeStr, SliceEscapeStr: String;
  BitsSlice: Byte): String;
var
  BMPData: TBitmapData;
  AColor: TAlphaColor;
  nCol, nRow, nIndex: integer;
  nOffset, nBytePos, nBitPos: integer;
  nSliceIndex, nLum: integer;
  nSlice, nBit, nTmpBit, BytesSlice: byte;
  ADots: Array of boolean;
  sSlice: String;
begin
  bmp.Map(TMapAccess.Read, BMPData);
  try
    SetLength(ADots, (BMP.Height * BMP.Width));
    nIndex := 0;

    for nRow := 0 to BMP.Height-1 do
    begin
      for nCol := 0 to BMP.Width-1 do
      begin
        AColor := BMPData.GetPixel(nCol, nRow);
        nLum := Trunc((TAlphaColorRec(AColor).R * 0.3)  + (TAlphaColorRec(AColor).G * 0.59) + (TAlphaColorRec(AColor).B * 0.11));
        ADots[nIndex] := (nLum < 127);
        inc(nIndex);
      end;
    end;

   BytesSlice := (BitsSlice div 8);

    if BitsSlice mod 8 > 0 then
      inc(BytesSlice);

    Result := EscapeStr;
    nOffset := 0;
    while (nOffset < BMP.Height) do
    begin
      Result := Result + SliceEscapeStr;

      for nCol := 0 to BMP.Width-1 do
      begin
        for nSliceIndex := 0 to BytesSlice - 1 do
        begin
          nSlice := 0;
          for nBit := 0 to 7 do
          begin
            nBytePos := (((nOffset div 8) + nSliceIndex) * 8) + nBit;
            nBitPos := (nBytePos * BMP.Width) + nCol;

            nTmpBit := 0;
            if (nBitPos < Length(ADots)) then
            begin
              if ADots[nBitPos] then
                nTmpBit := 1
              else
                nTmpBit := 0;
            end;
            nSlice := nSlice or (nTmpBit shl (7 - nBit));
          end;

          Result := Result + Chr(nSlice);
        end;
      end;

      inc(nOffset, BitsSlice);
      Result := Result + escNewLine;
    end;
finally
  bmp.Unmap(BMPData);
end;
end;
```

and I get this

[image]

Comment: I think you need to give more explanation of what your image conversion function is doing and what the resulting printout should look like.

Comment: This may help. The issue may be that you should use AnsiChar instead of Chr in BitmapToStr.
https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/4510-tbitmap-to-tbytes-for-escpos-thermal-printer/

Comment: What printer is that? There might be special commands available for printing 1D and 2D codes, so you can avoid the image overhead.

Comment: A920 Pro,   - https://www.paxtechnology.com/a920pro, I've tried everything possible, and I can't figure out what codes that shit uses.

Comment: Try contacting the support.

Comment: he won't tell me, because like I'm not a partner,
and the one who bought the device, they sent him, this
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-easily-implement-qrcoder-in-asp-net-core-using-c-10c4aa857e84/

Comment: I deleted my last comment, because the lib I mention there does only support VCL, afaik!

Comment: In any case, it will be difficult to get advice and answers unless the specifications of the ESC/POS control sequence supported by the printer of your indicated terminal are provided. Many printers will commonly support control sequences for printing characters, but whether or not they support printing images and barcodes (especially advanced 2D codes)? It depends strongly on the printer.

Comment: @kunif, the only solution is to find out which model is the printer in the terminal and then its ESC / POS codes

Comment: @kunif,   I found something

The A920 uses the Neptune API, is there a chance that sequences will be found there   [link]https://docs.hips.com/docs/pax-a920 [link]

Comment: The interface IPrinter at com.pax.dal on [SDK(API)](https://static.hips.com/software/pax/NeptuneLiteApi_V3.20.00_20201229.zip), which has a link on that page, describes those specifications, so why not check it out?

Comment: @kunif, https://www.twblogs.net/a/5b8d384b2b717718833c602b?lang=zh-cn      I found something, but I can't find ESC / POS codes anywhere, or which printer it would be.

Comment: It seems that there is no ESC/POS specification. It seems that a Java library is prepared instead.

Comment: @kunif - www.sam4s.co.kr/_common/ac_downFile.asp?f_url=/files/DOWN/2019012393432_1.pdf&f_name=SAM4S%20Printer%20Control%20Command%20Manual%20REV1_8.pdf  I found, I think this printer, to now run the qr-code command

Comment: If the vendor or model is different, there is a possibility that the support or not and the detailed specifications of the control code have changed. However, it is also important to actually send the command, so please give it a try.